# Add new entries into sql from ms access front end

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables which can be represented by this query (I have made this query the Recordsource of the form):

```
SELECT tblrcmtask.id, tblrcmtask.rcmtask,tblrcmtaskoptions.id, 
tblrcmtaskoptions.rcm_id,
tblrcmtaskoptions.rcmtaskoptions 
FROM tblrcmtask 
INNER JOIN tblrcmtaskoptions 
ON tblrcmtask.id=tblrcmtaskoptions.rcm_id
```

I want the user to be able to add new entries into these table via a form in access 2007.
Columns `tblrcmtask.id` and `tblrcmtaskoptions.id` are the primary keys of the tables `tblrcmtask` and `tblrcmtaskoptions` respectively.
I do not understand how do I create new ID in both the tables while the user adds new entries.The user can add only tblrcmtaskoptions.rcmtaskoptions and tblrcmtask.rcmtask in the form.Also, there are multiple rows in the table tblrcmtaskoptions for each tblrcmtask.id.
I want the user to be able to add new rows in the table tblrcmtaskoptions for an existing tblrcmtask.id

I tried using dropdowns for these two but I am facing problem while creating the new ID as Maximum of the ID + 1.

```
Dim MyRecords As DAO.Recordset 
Dim Myfield As DAO.Fields 
SQL = "SELECT Max(tblRCMTASK.ID) AS MaxOf_RCMTASKID FROM tblRCMTASK;" 
Set MyRecords = dbTHIS.OpenRecordset(SQL) 
Set Myfield = MyRecords.Fields 
Me.txtRCMTASKID = Myfield("MaxOf_RCMTASKID") + 1 
Me.txtRCMTASKID.DefaultValue = Myfield("MaxOf_RCMTASKID") + 1 
MyRecords.Close 
End If 
Dim MyRecords1 As DAO.Recordset 
Dim Myfield1 As DAO.Fields 
SQL = "SELECT Max(tblRCMTASKOPTIONS.ID) AS MaxOf_RCMOPTIONSID FROM tblRCMTASK;" 
Set MyRecords = dbTHIS.OpenRecordset(SQL) 
Set Myfield1 = MyRecords1.Fields 
Me.txtRCMOPTIONSID = Myfield1("MaxOf_RCMOPTIONSID") + 1 
Me.txtRCMOPTIONSID.DefaultValue = Myfield("MaxOf_RCMOPTIONSID") + 1 
MyRecords1.Close
```

I am getting an error which says you can't asign a value to this object and points to this line: Me.txtRCMTASKID = Myfield("MaxOf_RCMTASKID") + 1

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic form/subform set up. Create a form based solely on `tblrcmtask` with a subform `tblrcmtaskoptions`. The link child and master fields should be set to the common id. The wizards will do this for you. There is no code required. The id will be automatically added by the link fields.

You can see an example for in the [2007 version of the Northwind sample database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/templates/desktop-northwind-2007-sample-database-TC001228997.aspx).

Comment: I get the error "cannot insert null values into tblRCMTASKOPTIONS.ID" insert fails

Comment: when I edit the textbox that has the control source as tblRCMTASKOPTIONS.RCMTASKOPTIONS and then move to the next textbox to add another.But I am surprised this error doesn't exist for ttblRCMTask.ID.

Comment: Did you used the wizards to set up a form and subform? Do you have an autonumber on your main table?

Comment: I used form design to create the form and then the control subform onto that.Yes the autonumber is there on the main table

Comment: HOw do I stop users from adding an existing value again?

Comment: the form loads and the moment i select any value from the dropdown it is assigned a new ID and a new entry is made for it in the table.I want the user to know the existing values from dropdown and add new ones.

Comment: Does your subform not show the existing values? Where is the dropdown?

Comment: I have dropdowns instead of textboxes.The subform does show the existing value but as soon as I select one it is added as a new entry with ne ID.I think I shoud set limit to list property to yes and then use the not-in-list function to make new entries.

Answer (score 1):

Access gives you trouble when trying to do operations on an autonumber field. If you would like to do these kinds of operations, you may be better off just using a regular number as a PK.

To get a recently inserted autonumber field to insert the same number in a related table, this is the VBA:

assuming recordset and database are declared, rs and db

```
     dim id as integer
     set db = CurrentDb
     set rs = db.openrecordset("firstTable", dbOpenDynaSet)
 With rs
   .addNew
   .Fields("field1").Value = Me.control1   'adds to column1 of your table the value of control1
   .Fields("field2").Value = Me.control2
   .update                                 'updates the record. If it is an autonumber, it will be automatically assigned. I will show you how to access this for your next insert
 end with

 'To get the autoID of the entry we just inserted, do this
 id = db.OpenRecordSet("SELECT@@IDENTITY")(0)
 'Now you have the autoID of the recent insertion, so you may use it for your next one.
```

Comment: Access does not give you a lot of trouble when trying to use autonumbers. This case is very easy indeed, with the correct set-up, the numbers will be generated. People unfamiliar with MS Access nearly always write a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: As a new Access user, I can confirm this. I feel much safer coding everything in VBA than relying on wizards. That being said, I have used wizards for some forms, and am pleasantly surprised with the functionality.